# Install .net 3.5 on Windows 2008 R2 using DISM

Tags: .net

I'm writing an installer which uses DISM to enable features and roles on 2012 and 2008 R2.

I'm confused about where .Net 3.5 is located in server 2008. On 2012, I am aware that either online access is required or the OS media needs to be mounted.

On 2008 R2 however, I have just disabled network access and managed to install the .Net 3.5 feature. However, when I use the following DISM command I am unable to get the feature installed:
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /source:c\windows\winsxs /LimitAccess

I'm assuming that this is due to .net 3.5 not being in the winsxs folder.

Can anyone tell me where it is so I can use the dism command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so changing the above line in the dism from

dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /source:c\windows\winsxs /LimitAccess

to

dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3

installs the component ok. I disabled internet access so unlike server 2012 R2 you dont need to give 2008 R2 a location if you are not using the internet or the OS ISO.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mount windows 10 dvd
2. rus as administrator `cmd.exe`
3. run this command: `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /Source:g:\sources\sxs`

note: "g:" is the drive that windows 10 has mounted